# ¿Como puedo quitar el borde de la columa de numeros sin afectar el lugar y las demas celdas?

Tags: tablas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>Presidencia Municipal</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            .contenedor {
                width: 1100px; 
                height: 930px; 
                padding-top: 10px;
                border: 1px solid none;
                margin: auto;
            }

            .centro {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .izquierda{
              background-color: none;
              width:250px;
              float: left;
              padding-left: 30px;
            }

            .bloque{
              text-align: center;
              background: none;
              height:50px;
            }

            table
            {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                border-left: 0px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
<body>

    <div class="contenedor">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">

        PRESIDENCIA MUNICIPAL

            <span>

                <img src="media/logo.png" height="100px" style="float: left; padding-left: 16%;">

                    </span>
            <span>

                <img src="media/escudo.png" height="100px" style="float: right; padding-right: 10%;">

                    </span>

        <br>R. AYTO. 2019-2021
        <br>MATAMOROS, COAH.

    </h2>


        <h3 class="centro">MANIFIESTO DE NO CONFLICTO DE INTERES</h3>

            <p style="padding-left: 180px; font-size: 1.05em;">

                Fundamiento en los articulos 25-A y 25-B, las fracciones XVII y XVIII del articulo 50, la fracci&oacuten VI del articulo

                    <br>79 de la Ley de Obras  P&uacuteblicas y Servicios Relacionados con las Mismaspara el Estado de Coahuila de Zaragoza;

                        <br>y los articulos 42,42-A, 42B, fracciones II,XV,XVI, XVII y XVII del articulo 73, fracci&oacuten VI del articulo 84 de la

                            <br>reconociendo el alcance legal y tipo de responsabilidad civil o penal que de esto se derive:

            </p>

        <h3 class="centro">

            MANIFIESTO QUE:

        </h3>

        <br>

        <h3 style="padding-left: 180px">

            (Marque con una X la respuesta)

        </h3>

    <div style="padding-left: 180px;">

        <table border="1">

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px">1</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px;">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten personal con alg&uacuten servidor p&uacuteblico de la dependencia a entidad contratantede la cual pueda

                            <br>obtener un beneficio

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                    <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                    <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                    <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                        </p>
                                            </td>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px">2</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten familiar por consanguinidad hasta el cuarto grado, afinidad o civil, con alg&uacuten servicio p&uacuteblico

                            <br>que elabore para la dependecia o entidad contratante

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                    <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                    <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                    <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                        </p>

                                            </td>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px" style="border-color: none;">3</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten personales, laborales, o de negocios formales o informales con alg&uacuten servidor p&uacuteblico que

                            <br>la dependecia a entidad contratante o con alguno de sus familiares por consaguinidad hasta el cuarto grado,

                                <br>afinidad o civiles.

                                    <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                        <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                        <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                        <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                            </p>

                                                </td>
            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px">4</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;">

                        <p>Soy socio o he formado parte de una sociedad con alg&uacute servidor p&uacuteblico que labore para la dependecia o
                            <br>entidad contratante o con sus familiares por consaguinidad hasta el cuato grado, afinidad o civiles.

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, asi como nombre y tipo de

                                    <br>sociedad.

                                        <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                        <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                        <br>Nombre de la Sociedad:__________________________
                                        <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                            </p>

                                                </td>
            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="50px">5</td>
                <td width="20px" height="50px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="50px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="50px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 3px;">

                        <p>
                            Soy empleada o empleado actual de la dependencia o entidad contratante.
                        </p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el codigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>Presidencia Municipal</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            .contenedor {
                width: 1100px; 
                height: 930px; 
                padding-top: 10px;
                border: 1px solid none;
                margin: auto;
            }

            .centro {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .izquierda{
              background-color: none;
              width:250px;
              float: left;
              padding-left: 30px;
            }

            .bloque{
              text-align: center;
              background: none;
              height:50px;
            }

            table
            {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                border-left: 0px;
            }

            .td-num{
                border-left: none;
                border-top: none;
                border-bottom: none;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
<body>

    <div class="contenedor">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">

        PRESIDENCIA MUNICIPAL

            <span>

                <img src="media/logo.png" height="100px" style="float: left; padding-left: 16%;">

                    </span>
            <span>

                <img src="media/escudo.png" height="100px" style="float: right; padding-right: 10%;">

                    </span>

        <br>R. AYTO. 2019-2021
        <br>MATAMOROS, COAH.

    </h2>


        <h3 class="centro">MANIFIESTO DE NO CONFLICTO DE INTERES</h3>

            <p style="padding-left: 180px; font-size: 1.05em;">

                Fundamiento en los articulos 25-A y 25-B, las fracciones XVII y XVIII del articulo 50, la fracci&oacuten VI del articulo

                    <br>79 de la Ley de Obras  P&uacuteblicas y Servicios Relacionados con las Mismaspara el Estado de Coahuila de Zaragoza;

                        <br>y los articulos 42,42-A, 42B, fracciones II,XV,XVI, XVII y XVII del articulo 73, fracci&oacuten VI del articulo 84 de la

                            <br>reconociendo el alcance legal y tipo de responsabilidad civil o penal que de esto se derive:

            </p>

        <h3 class="centro">

            MANIFIESTO QUE:

        </h3>

        <br>

        <h3 style="padding-left: 180px">

            (Marque con una X la respuesta)

        </h3>

    <div style="padding-left: 180px;">

        <table>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px" class="td-num">1</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px;">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten personal con alg&uacuten servidor p&uacuteblico de la dependencia a entidad contratantede la cual pueda

                            <br>obtener un beneficio

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                    <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                    <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                    <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                        </p>
                                            </td>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px" class="td-num">2</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten familiar por consanguinidad hasta el cuarto grado, afinidad o civil, con alg&uacuten servicio p&uacuteblico

                            <br>que elabore para la dependecia o entidad contratante

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                    <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                    <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                    <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                        </p>

                                            </td>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px" style="border-color: none;" class="td-num">3</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten personales, laborales, o de negocios formales o informales con alg&uacuten servidor p&uacuteblico que

                            <br>la dependecia a entidad contratante o con alguno de sus familiares por consaguinidad hasta el cuarto grado,

                                <br>afinidad o civiles.

                                    <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                        <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                        <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                        <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                            </p>

                                                </td>
            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px" class="td-num">4</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;">

                        <p>Soy socio o he formado parte de una sociedad con alg&uacute servidor p&uacuteblico que labore para la dependecia o
                            <br>entidad contratante o con sus familiares por consaguinidad hasta el cuato grado, afinidad o civiles.

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, asi como nombre y tipo de

                                    <br>sociedad.

                                        <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                        <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                        <br>Nombre de la Sociedad:__________________________
                                        <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                            </p>

                                                </td>
            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="50px" class="td-num">5</td>
                <td width="20px" height="50px">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="50px">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="50px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 3px;">

                        <p>
                            Soy empleada o empleado actual de la dependencia o entidad contratante.
                        </p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obtendrias esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si es lo que quieres hacer, al menos eso entendí, si no puedes volver a formular tu pregunta y con gusto te ayudo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que trabajes con `clases`.

Un ejemplo:
-le damos estilo a las etiquetas `td` (en la que NO le damos borde).
-creamos una clase `.borde` (que a la que sí que le damos un borde)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>Presidencia Municipal</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            .contenedor {
                width: 1100px; 
                height: 930px; 
                padding-top: 10px;
                border: 1px solid none;
                margin: auto;
            }

            .centro {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .izquierda{
              background-color: none;
              width:250px;
              float: left;
              padding-left: 30px;
            }

            .bloque{
              text-align: center;
              background: none;
              height:50px;
            }

            table
            {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td
            {
                padding: 5px;
                border-left: 0px;
            }
            td.borde
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
<body>

    <div class="contenedor">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">

        PRESIDENCIA MUNICIPAL

            <span>

                <img src="media/logo.png" height="100px" style="float: left; padding-left: 16%;">

                    </span>
            <span>

                <img src="media/escudo.png" height="100px" style="float: right; padding-right: 10%;">

                    </span>

        <br>R. AYTO. 2019-2021
        <br>MATAMOROS, COAH.

    </h2>


        <h3 class="centro">MANIFIESTO DE NO CONFLICTO DE INTERES</h3>

            <p style="padding-left: 180px; font-size: 1.05em;">

                Fundamiento en los articulos 25-A y 25-B, las fracciones XVII y XVIII del articulo 50, la fracci&oacuten VI del articulo

                    <br>79 de la Ley de Obras  P&uacuteblicas y Servicios Relacionados con las Mismaspara el Estado de Coahuila de Zaragoza;

                        <br>y los articulos 42,42-A, 42B, fracciones II,XV,XVI, XVII y XVII del articulo 73, fracci&oacuten VI del articulo 84 de la

                            <br>reconociendo el alcance legal y tipo de responsabilidad civil o penal que de esto se derive:

            </p>

        <h3 class="centro">

            MANIFIESTO QUE:

        </h3>

        <br>

        <h3 style="padding-left: 180px">

            (Marque con una X la respuesta)

        </h3>

    <div style="padding-left: 180px;">

        <table>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px">1</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px;" class="borde">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten personal con alg&uacuten servidor p&uacuteblico de la dependencia a entidad contratantede la cual pueda

                            <br>obtener un beneficio

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                    <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                    <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                    <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                        </p>
                                            </td>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px">2</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;" class="borde">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten familiar por consanguinidad hasta el cuarto grado, afinidad o civil, con alg&uacuten servicio p&uacuteblico

                            <br>que elabore para la dependecia o entidad contratante

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                    <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                    <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                    <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                        </p>

                                            </td>

            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px">3</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;" class="borde">

                        <p>Tengo relaci&oacuten personales, laborales, o de negocios formales o informales con alg&uacuten servidor p&uacuteblico que

                            <br>la dependecia a entidad contratante o con alguno de sus familiares por consaguinidad hasta el cuarto grado,

                                <br>afinidad o civiles.

                                    <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, as&iacute como el tipo de relaci&oacuten.

                                        <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                        <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                        <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                            </p>

                                                </td>
            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="100px">4</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="100px" class="borde">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="100px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px; font-size: 0.98em;" class="borde">

                        <p>Soy socio o he formado parte de una sociedad con alg&uacute servidor p&uacuteblico que labore para la dependecia o
                            <br>entidad contratante o con sus familiares por consaguinidad hasta el cuato grado, afinidad o civiles.

                                <br>Si la respuesta es SI, escriba nombre y cargo de servidor p&uacuteblico relacionado, asi como nombre y tipo de

                                    <br>sociedad.

                                        <br>Nombre:______________________________________
                                        <br>Cargo:________________________________________
                                        <br>Nombre de la Sociedad:__________________________
                                        <br>Tipo de relaci&oacuten:________________________________

                                            </p>

                                                </td>
            <tr style="text-align: center;">

                <td width="10px" height="50px">5</td>
                <td width="20px" height="50px" class="borde">SI</td>
                <td width="20px" height="50px" class="borde">NO</td>

                    <td width="690px" height="50px" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 3px;" class="borde">

                        <p>
                            Soy empleada o empleado actual de la dependencia o entidad contratante.
                        </p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```